# Why am I able to access a non-static method in a static context when using dynamic

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

The following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic d = 0;

        int x = Test.TestDynamic(d);
        int y = Test.TestInt(0);
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public int TestDynamic(dynamic data)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public int TestInt(int data)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

when run in Visual Studio 2013 (Update 5), raises a compile time error on the line with Test.TestInt

> "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property."

but does not raise the same error on the Test.TestDynamic line. It does fail, expectedly, with a runtime error.

The same code raises a compile time error on both lines in Visual Studio 2015.

Why is the same compile time error not raised in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: visual studio 2015 has a brand new compiler, so the rules may have changed.

Comment: Indeed, it sounds like it's probably just a bug with the old compiler.

Comment: Darn, I was hoping for some crazy edge case where the code actually ran, or some limitation because of the way the old compiler worked with dynamic. Oh well, post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1):

You can't access properties / method without creating an instance of the object.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic d = 0;

        Test test = new Test();
        int x = test.TestDynamic(d);
        int y = test.TestInt(0);
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public int TestDynamic(dynamic data)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public int TestInt(int data)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. My question is about the difference in behaviour between VS 2013 and VS 2015 (or rather, their compilers, as the comments mention). Obviously the Roslyn behaviour is correct, but I'm wondering whether the behaviour in VS 2013 is a bug or a consequence of the limitations of the previous compiler.